# Attributes are not updated in configurable goods

Tags: configurable-product

I have 2 attributes (size,colors) set in my configurable products (and showing in select list) and I need delete one of them. I did it and, for new goods, new settings, it works. But old products still have 2 attributes, how can I reset attributes for existing goods?

**Note :** Re-index does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It is not intended to delete attributes which are used in configurable products, and theoretically there should be a lot of reasons this is not possible:

If there is a product using an attribute set and an attribute set using the attribute, you should get an error while deleting.

So: How did you delete the attribute?! I you deleted the attribute in the database, the behavior you encounter is unpredictable.